# Cauchy integral formula explanation

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following problem:

evaluate $$\int_C \frac{\sin z}{4z+\pi}\,dz.$$

I take $f(z) = \sin z$ and $$\int_C \frac{\sin z}{4z+\pi}\,dz  = \frac{1}{4} \int_C \frac{\sin z}{z-(-\frac{\pi}{4})}\,dz.$$

I equate $$\sin z = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\frac{1}{4}\int_C \frac{sin z}{z-(-\frac{\pi}{4})},$$ and obtain the answer of $\displaystyle{2\pi i\sin\left(\frac{-\pi}{4}\right)}$, but this is not correct. I understand that I should divide the left hand side by $4$ rather than multiply, but I do not understand why. Please help me to understand! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cauchy integral formula is
$$
\oint \frac{f(z)}{z - z_0} = 2\pi i f(z_0)
$$
assuming that the loop is around a sufficiently small disc around $z_0$ so that $f(z)$ is holomorphic on that disc.

In your case, you want to compute
$$
\oint \frac{\sin z}{4z + \pi} = \frac{1}{4}\underbrace{\oint \frac{\sin(z)}{z - (-\pi/4)}}_{\text{Cauchy Integral formula applies to this part}}
$$
which by the CIF the left-hand-side is now
$$
\frac{1}{4}\big(2\pi i \sin(-\pi/4)\big) = -\frac{\pi i}{2}\sin(\pi/4) = -\frac{\pi i}{2\sqrt{2}}
$$

Comment: but why does factoring the left hand side of the cauchy integral formula imply dividing the right by that factor?

Comment: Compare the underbraced part of the answer to the CIF above. You have that
$$
\oint \frac{\sin z}{z - (-\pi/4)} = 2\pi i \sin(-\pi/4)
$$
and so substituting this value in gives what you're looking for.

Comment: Remember that you're trying to evaluate the original integral; your factoring yields that it is
$$
\oint \frac{\sin z}{4z + \pi} = \frac{1}{4}(\text{whatever you get from the CIF})
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(-\pi/4) = \frac1{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{\sin z}{z-(-\frac{\pi}4)}\,dz,$$
$$\frac{\pi i}2\sin(-\pi/4)= 2\pi i\frac14\sin(-\pi/4) = \frac14\int_C \frac{\sin z}{z-(-\frac{\pi}{4})}\,dz = \int_C\frac{\sin z}{4z+\pi}\,dz.$$

Answer (score 0):

The Cauchy integral formula says that:
$$
\int_{C}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_{0}}dz=2\pi if(z_{0})
$$
where $C$ is a simple closed curve which contains $z_{0}$. In your integral if $C$ contains $-\pi/4$ then
$$
\int_{C}\frac{\sin(z)}{4z+\pi}dz=\frac{1}{4}\int_{C}\frac{\sin(z)}{z-(-\frac{\pi}{4})}dz=(\frac{1}{4})(2\pi i)\sin(\frac{-\pi}{4}).
$$